# Place a Yes or No in an excel spreadsheet based on a value

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

Thanks in Advance!

Here is the code:I want to gather the value of the below variable...

```
 $Sheet3.Cells.Item($intRowDisk, 4) = $objItem.Size/1024/1024/1024 - $objItem.FreeSpace/1024/1024/1024
```

Then I want to compare that value and if it is larger than 100 GB place a value of yes or no in a column within an excel spreadsheet.

```
 if ( $Sheet3.Cells.Item($intRowDisk, 4) -gt 100 ) {
            $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 12) = write "Yes"
```

But I get the error of : ERROR: Bad argument to operator '-gt': Could not compare "System.__ComObject" to "100". Error: "Cannot convert the "100" value of type "System.Int32" to type "System.
ERROR: __ComObject".".
IME_InventoryV1.8.ps1 (124): ERROR: At Line: 124 char: 49
ERROR: +                     if ( $Sheet3.Cells.Item($intRowDisk, 4) -gt <<<<  100 ) {
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to add a variable and then feed the variable to the if statement.  It now works like a charm.

```
$Sheet3.Cells.Item($intRowDisk, 4) = $objItem.Size/1024/1024/1024 - $objItem.FreeSpace/1024/1024/1024   

        $valueforif = $objItem.Size/1024/1024/1024 - $objItem.FreeSpace/1024/1024/1024

        if ( $valueforif -gt 100 )
                    {
            $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 12) = "Yes"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `write "Yes"` inside your if block? Does simply assigning "Yes" not work?

`write` is an alias for the [Write-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849921.aspx) cmdlet, which puts content on the pipeline for the next command. It probably isn't what you want to use in this case. Try just assigning the string `"Yes"` and see if that solves your issue.

Also, on your comparison - while not particularly helpful, PowerShell is telling you that you can't compare a COM object and the value 100. You need to include a call to actually get the value out of the COM object for comparison by including the method invocation **Value()** at the end of your expression:

```
$Sheet3.Cells.Item($intRowDisk, 4).Value()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Goyuix.  Unfortunately that did not work. Is there a way of converting a com object to something else?  The error is referencing this portion of code :if ( $Sheet3.Cells.Item($intRowDisk, 4) -gt 100 ) which I guess means that the value is not a value that I can read?  I thought it would be the current value in the spread sheet which is an integer...